# SQL Query for paramaterized dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

One of the product teams I manage has an abundance of queries that use dynamic sql queries injecting the table in using concatenation. While it has sanitisation, I am trying to completely remove dynamic sql.

Is there a way to parameterise the table name?
I am trying to think of how I can query a table something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Table_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE Table_Name = :queryParam)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot parameterize identifiers in SQL queries.  You can use `QUOTENAME()` to be more careful:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql.

Comment: @GordonLinoff These are inline string queries and not Stored Procs, so QUOTENAME won't help as someone could still escape its bounds. Thanks though.

Comment: @Cyassin _I am trying to completely remove dynamic sql_, you can't do it without dynamic sql.

Comment: *Is it possible (as shown in question)?* = No.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to completely remove dynamic sql.

- You can't do it without `Dynamic SQL`.

> Is this possible?

- No, it's not possible, you cannot parameterize identifiers in SQL queries.

> Why?

- From the Books online page for **[Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql)**, `Variables` can be used only in expressions, not in place of `object names` or `keywords`. To construct `dynamic SQL` statements, use `EXECUTE`.

---

This is the only way to do it:

```
DECLARE @Column SysName = N'Table_Name',
        @Param NVARCHAR(128) = N'ParamValue';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'SELECT *
                             FROM(
                                   SELECT '+ QUOTENAME(@Column) +
                                   'FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
                                    WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + ' = @Param
                                 ) T';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQl,
                      N'@Param NVARCHAR(128)',
                      @Param;
```

Comment: using an ORM / building a strongly typed data layer would solve this problem for you. The fact that you are in this situation implies that you are trying to build a data layer (essentially the work of an ORM) ... given the situation you present it's impossible for someone to give you a complete answer to your problem in a SO post. If YOU are generating raw SQL strings then YOU are responsible for checking YOUR string inputs for SQL injections. perhaps consider reading the source code of something EF or Hibernate to understand what you are asking (in particular the query generation code).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "properly" prevent SQL injection completely from within SQL, the calling application layer should do this prior to executing any SQL statement.

Solve the problem by using an ORM or building the code to protect yourself from SQL injection when you generate the SQL in the application code.

This feels like a classic XY problem, try to take a step back and consider that you need to protect the access to the SQL server itself rather than sanitise everything from within "after" your SQL server has been accessed.